# Understanding the Scapy "Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast." warning

Tags: python, scapy

If I generate an Ethernet frame without any upper layers payload and send it at layer two with sendp(), then I receive the `"Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast."` warning and frame put to wire indeed uses ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff as a destination MAC address. Why is this so? Shouldn't the Scapy send exactly the frame I constructed?

My crafted package can be seen below:

```
>>> ls(x)
dst        : DestMACField         = '01:00:0c:cc:cc:cc' (None)
src        : SourceMACField       = '00:11:22:33:44:55' (None)
type       : XShortEnumField      = 0               (0)
>>> sendp(x, iface="eth0")
WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
.
Sent 1 packets.
>>>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you post the line you used to create the packet, your scapy version, and the platform you're running on?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Most people encountering this issue are incorrectly using `send()`** (or `sr()`, `sr1()`, `srloop()`) **instead of `sendp()`** (or `srp()`, `srp1()`, `srploop()`). For the record, the "without-`p`" functions like `send()` are for sending layer 3 packets (`send(IP())`) while the "with-`p`" variants are for sending layer 2 packets (`sendp(Ether() / IP())`).

If you define `x` like I do below and use `sendp()` (and not `send()`) and you still have this issue, you should probably try with the latest version from the project's git repository (see https://github.com/secdev/scapy).

I've tried:

```
>>> x = Ether(src='01:00:0c:cc:cc:cc', dst='00:11:22:33:44:55')
>>> ls(x)
dst        : DestMACField         = '00:11:22:33:44:55' (None)
src        : SourceMACField       = '01:00:0c:cc:cc:cc' (None)
type       : XShortEnumField      = 0               (0)
>>> sendp(x, iface='eth0')
.
Sent 1 packets.
```

At the same time I was running tcpdump:

```
# tcpdump -eni eth0 ether host 00:11:22:33:44:55
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
12:33:47.774570 01:00:0c:cc:cc:cc > 00:11:22:33:44:55, 802.3, length 14: [|llc]
```